# how can I start a thread with IOS system ?( using swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I need to start a thread with an ios, but I don't know how.

I don't have experience with swift, I'm new in this. In android I would do a broadcast receiver and "listen" when android started, but in IOS I'm lost :s

Someone knows how to do it using swift?

Comment: You can use `NSThread`, but that's generally frowned upon and we use dispatch or operation queues for our asynchronous code nowadays. (See [Migrating Away From Threads](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW1) in the _Concurrency Programming Guide._) It depends upon what you're trying to do. Some broader context of the question will probably get you better answers.

Comment: I think it would be much more useful if you told us what you actually want to achieve. You can install all kinds of observers, but that has all nothing to do with threads, so at this point any answer would be pure guesswork.

Comment: I suggest using NSOperationQueue, it's very simple. Read more: http://www.raywenderlich.com/76341/use-nsoperation-nsoperationqueue-swift

Comment: I just need to do a http request.
My App need to check a response resquest and change a information using NSUserDefaults

Answer (score 0):

You can't run a thing similiar to an Android service on iOS.

iOS is very strict about executing code in background.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using NSOperationQueue

```
let queue = NSOperationQueue()
queue.addOperationWithBlock {
    // do something here
}
```

Read more documentation here:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/76341/use-nsoperation-nsoperationqueue-swift